# Asynchronous function with exec ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, asynchronous, exec

hi I have an error on running this asynchronous function, this asynchronous function makes a call to the ruby ​​file! Should I set the code so that the asynchronous function waits for the termination of the exec and base64.encode, how can I do?

```
async function GenerazioneRapportino() {
  var encode="false";

  console.log("Model: sono dentor model");
  //Cambio direttorio
  process.chdir('./Model');
  // console.log("directory:",process.cwd());
  exec('ruby report.rb prova prova2 prova3', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if(stderr) {  
      console.log("Errore generazione rapportino: ",err);  
      return encode;  
    } else {
      console.log("File Generator Correttamente: ",stdout);
      base64.encode('rapportino.pdf', function(err, base64String) {
        encode=base64String;             
        process.chdir('../');
        console.log("Process dir ",process.cwd());
        return encode;
      });
    }

  });

  console.log("Model: Ritorno encode");
  return encode;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `async` function, you should convert your callbacks into a Promise and `await` that Promise to get the desired value. Note that there's no need to reassign (or use) the outer `encode` variable:

```
async function GenerazioneRapportino() {
  console.log("Model: sono dentor model");
  process.chdir('./Model');
  const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec('ruby report.rb prova prova2 prova3', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      if (stderr) {
        console.log("Errore generazione rapportino: ", err);
        reject(false);
      } else {
        console.log("File Generator Correttamente: ", stdout);
        base64.encode('rapportino.pdf', function(err, base64String) {
          process.chdir('../');
          console.log("Process dir ", process.cwd());
          resolve(base64String);
        });
      }
    });
  });
  console.log("Model: Ritorno encode");
  return result;
}
```

Note that using `await` inside `async` functions will result in errors being thrown if the promise is rejected - make sure that the consumer of `GenerazioneRapportino` calls the function in a `try` block.